# return object from dictionary of nested lists when a condition (python)

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary, numpy

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
myD={'key_0':[[['descrp_0_0'],Obj_0_0],.....,[['descrp_0_N'],obj_0_N]]
 ,.....,
 'key_N':[[['descrp_N_0'],Obj_N_0],.....,[['descrp_N_N'],obj_N_N]]}
```

All objs are ndarrays of the same shape and have a function f() that returns an x which is a float i.e.:
    obj_0_0.f() --> x_0_0

I want to extract a dictionary with the descrp and obj and their respective key where obj.f() (i.e. x) is minimum for the values in each key (at the myD scope of N keys would give N items in shape of [descrp,obj]):

The result must look something like:

```
resD = {'key_0':[[descrp_0_min],obj_0_min],
    .....,
     'key_N':[[descrp_N_min],obj_0_min]}
```

Something like:

```
minXs = [min([item[-1].f() for item in v]) for k,v in myD.iteritems()]

minObjs = [item for k,v in myD.iteritems() for item in v if item[-1].get_potential_energy() == minXs[myD.keys().index(k)]]

resultList = zip(myD.keys(),minObjs)
resultDict = dict()
for i in resultList:
     resultDict[i[0]]=i[1]
```

Although it works but is rather cumbersome and I think there must be an easier way to do this. Or maybe I should use *numpy.ndarray* for this purpose?

I appreciate your help and comments.

Comment: Is your dictionary missing a `[` character at the start of each value? That is, does the key `key_0` correspond to the whole list `[[['descrp_0_0'],Obj_0_0],.....,[['descrp_0_N'],obj_0_N]]` (note the extra `[` I've added), or just to the first item?

Comment: It corresponds to the whole list. An extra bracket as you said was needed so I edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the structure of your data correctly, I think you can solve this with a dictionary comprehension that calls the builtin `min` function and gives it a `key` function.

```
results = {key: min(values, key=lambda x:x[-1].f())
           for key, values in myD.iteritems()}
```

Your code was really close already!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer and efficient method. However, this seems to disregard one layer in the array i.e. **myD.values()[i][j][-1]** is the object that has the f() function. I tried: 

    `results = {key:min(values,key=lambda x:x[i][-1].f() for key,values in myD.iteritems() for i in values}` 

which again throws a SyntaxError at the first 'for' occurrence.

Comment: @AliRafieefar: I'm not sure if I understand the extra layer you're talking about. The dictionary is the outermost layer and we're explicitly iterating over it in the comprehension. The `values` list is next innermost layer, which is iterated over implicitly by `min`. The items inside of that are also lists, like `[['descrip_0_0'],Obj_0_0]` which is what the lambda indexes. I did have a typo in my code (`value` instead of `values`). Could that be the problem you were hitting?

Comment: You were right about the layers. I figured out since I'm using Python 2.6, the syntax for dictionary comprehension must be:
`results = dict((key,min(values,key=lambda x:x[-1].f())) for key,values in myD.iteritems())`
Thanks